# Collectionview image cell scroll issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**When the app is first opened.**

[image]

However, when I scroll down and go up again, the size of the image views gets smaller. What is the reason of this ? I am using storyboard.

**Cell Resizing Code:**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        flowLayout?.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        flowLayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        flowLayout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        let size = CGSize(width:(bookCollectionView.bounds.width-30)/2, height: 270)
        
        return size
    }
```

**After scroll**

[image]

Image Constraints:

Image constraints = (0,0,0,0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I changed the `Estimate Size` of CollectionView from Storyboard to `None`.

[image]